# Botframework V4: post-process middleware

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm looking for a solution into Botframework SDK v4 (Node.js version) which aims to do some process at the very end of the SDK's workflow.

My objectif is to be able to log a trace at the very end of the process to display lot of informations collected during the current TurnContext (user's message, bot's message, intent from LUIS, entities from LUIS, ...).

Is there something like this into Botframework SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to log telemetry, so you might be interested in [telemetryLoggerMiddleware](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/telemetryLoggerMiddleware.ts)

To answer your question, yes it's easy to implement post-logic processing in middleware. Just put your code after you await `next` in `onTurn`. [autoSaveStateMiddleware](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/autoSaveStateMiddleware.ts) is a good example of this:

```
public async onTurn(context: TurnContext, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> {
    await next();
    await this.botStateSet.saveAllChanges(context, false);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, it's sound good ! But I haven't found any documentation about Middleware into Botframework's documentation. Do you have one ?

Comment: Yes, right here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware